# Ubuntu 16.04: takes too long to boot

Tags: boot, 16.04

My system is very slow boot. I don't have an SSD but more than 2min for boot seems pretty slow. I did some look up and found some commands to analyze the problem. Most answers don't tell what to do when something is wrong. So I added the command and results below. It would be nice if someone could tell me what is wrong and how to solve it.

```
$ sudo blkid 
/dev/sda1: UUID="FEA0B616A0B5D4FD" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="a71f19d9-505f-4418-9c64-7375c82a2ebc"
/dev/sda2: UUID="1CB9-3478" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="68365181-1cc5-49be-b410-f38bb970a4ed"
/dev/sda3: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="c788a6b3-9548-462e-abf9-83e3b83930a1"
/dev/sda4: UUID="943CCB4F3CCB2AD6" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="173aab50-5018-453b-911b-7b7046b43529"
/dev/sda5: UUID="D67AD7DE7AD7BA07" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="aff48723-c367-4c8d-a714-e2fba4befdc6"
/dev/sda6: LABEL="Software" UUID="01D15FA547B54680" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="7bbcb884-25e7-11e3-be6a-806e6f6e6963"
/dev/sda7: UUID="455447e5-66d0-4924-807f-ff0038925ca5" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="6e87e5ce-31e6-45f5-98f1-2478d8c2942e"
/dev/sda8: LABEL="Study" UUID="6852DB2952DAFAB0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="2c49bf2a-b4dc-4a23-be44-df6ce93db46a"
/dev/sda9: LABEL="Other" UUID="FC08523A0851F3DC" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="a9b1b2b0-74f1-49f1-883d-068f9d52ad49"
/dev/sda10: UUID="531f8eb3-9806-48e4-865f-c61bf5bb25d4" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="6d992b5a-7812-46e9-99b9-6a1345939066"
```

---

```
$ cat /etc/fstab 

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda10 during installation
UUID=531f8eb3-9806-48e4-865f-c61bf5bb25d4 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=1CB9-3478  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=455447e5-66d0-4924-807f-ff0038925ca5 none            swap    sw              0       0
#mount Other drive
UUID=FC08523A0851F3DC /home/bcc/drives/ ntfs rw,auto,users,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=46,uid=1000    0   0
```

---

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
 37.229s apt-daily.service
     11.700s ModemManager.service
      8.808s dev-sda10.device
      6.708s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1CB9\x2d3478.service
      5.548s NetworkManager.service
      5.304s home-bcc-drives.mount
      4.825s accounts-daemon.service
      3.800s thermald.service
      3.697s grub-common.service
      2.847s lightdm.service
      2.524s apparmor.service
      2.464s setvtrgb.service
      2.182s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      1.958s gpu-manager.service
      1.905s preload.service
      1.726s ondemand.service
      1.483s polkitd.service
      1.402s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      1.360s keyboard-setup.service
      1.195s systemd-logind.service
      1.171s systemd-timesyncd.service
      1.074s irqbalance.service
      1.069s plymouth-start.service
       966ms systemd-modules-load.service
       908ms apport.service
       893ms systemd-udevd.service
       876ms systemd-journald.service
       823ms networking.service
       722ms avahi-daemon.service
       722ms wpa_supplicant.service
       678ms dev-hugepages.mount
       666ms rsyslog.service
       595ms colord.service
       585ms dev-mqueue.mount
       582ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       463ms binfmt-support.service
       407ms udisks2.service
       368ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       323ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       323ms rc-local.service
       303ms console-setup.service
       280ms upower.service
       273ms systemd-rfkill.service
       273ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
       266ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       249ms ufw.service
       186ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       181ms systemd-sysctl.service
       156ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       150ms dev-sda7.swap
       148ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
       130ms speech-dispatcher.service
       127ms systemd-random-seed.service
       126ms dns-clean.service
       116ms boot-efi.mount
       110ms snapd.socket
        98ms systemd-user-sessions.service
        95ms systemd-journal-flush.service
        48ms pppd-dns.service
        36ms resolvconf.service
        31ms plymouth-read-write.service
        28ms user@1000.service
        27ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
        19ms alsa-restore.service
        18ms snapd.autoimport.service
         5ms ureadahead-stop.service
         4ms rtkit-daemon.service
         4ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         3ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
         3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
```

I removed some lines from the output of `dmesg` below, but kept the ones that seemed important

```
[    0.000000] hpet clockevent registered
[    0.000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration using PIT
[    0.000000] tsc: Detected 1895.673 MHz processor
[    0.000036] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 3791.34 BogoMIPS (lpj=7582692)
[    0.000039] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.000052] ACPI: Core revision 20160422
[    0.011000] ACPI: 4 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded

[    0.025359] Security Framework initialized

[    0.511918] pci 0000:00:02.0: Video device with shadowed ROM at [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
[    2.511497] pci 0000:00:1a.0: EHCI: BIOS handoff failed (BIOS bug?) 01010001
[    4.539517] pci 0000:00:1d.0: EHCI: BIOS handoff failed (BIOS bug?) 01010001
[    4.539738] PCI: CLS 64 bytes, default 64
[    4.539799] Unpacking initramfs...
[    5.291433] Freeing initrd memory: 39500K (ffff8ec2fd968000 - ffff8ec2ffffb000)
[    5.291436] PCI-DMA: Using software bounce buffering for IO (SWIOTLB)

[    6.439793] hid-generic 0003:062A:5918.0003: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.1/input1
[    6.504954] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0129
[    6.504956] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    6.504958] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB2.0-CRW
[    6.504959] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Generic
[    6.504960] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 20100201396000000
[    6.510251] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtsx_usb
[    6.533397] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd00123/0x840300/0x127c00/0x0, board id: 2133, fw id: 1468684
[    6.583556] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[    6.605686] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
[    6.789195] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=13d3, idProduct=5171
[    6.789198] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[    6.789199] usb 1-1.4: Product: Lenovo EasyCamera
[    6.789200] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Azurewave
[    6.789202] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: NULL
[    7.327672] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    7.653632] EXT4-fs (sda10): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    8.872137] random: crng init done
[    9.137406] systemd[1]: systemd 229 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN)
[    9.137581] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[    9.147618] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <bcc>.
[   10.877351] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[   10.877450] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[   10.877509] systemd[1]: Started Trigger resolvconf update for networkd DNS.
[   10.877600] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[   10.877641] systemd[1]: Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[   10.877655] systemd[1]: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
[   10.877681] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[   11.767225] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   11.888794] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   13.737580] EXT4-fs (sda10): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   13.787306] systemd-journald[267]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[   14.203491] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000400-0x000000000000047F (\PMIO) (20160422/utaddress-255)
[   14.203498] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   14.203501] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20160422/utaddress-255)
[   14.203504] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   14.203505] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20160422/utaddress-255)
[   14.203508] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   14.203509] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20160422/utaddress-255)
[   14.203511] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   14.203512] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[   14.234143] wmi: Mapper loaded
[   14.453704] input: Ideapad extra buttons as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/input/input9
[   14.620378] RAPL PMU: API unit is 2^-32 Joules, 3 fixed counters, 163840 ms ovfl timer
[   14.620380] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp0-core 2^-16 Joules
[   14.620381] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain package 2^-16 Joules
[   14.620381] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp1-gpu 2^-16 Joules
[   14.768199] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[   15.374420] input: eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch EXC7910-1018-08.00.00 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0/0003:0EEF:A107.0001/input/input10
[   15.374589] hid-multitouch 0003:0EEF:A107.0001: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v2.10 Device [eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch EXC7910-1018-08.00.00] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0
[   15.477029] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC269VC: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[   15.477033] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   15.477036] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x15/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   15.477038] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   15.477039] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[   15.477042] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x18
[   15.477045] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[   15.646761] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[   15.780221] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[   15.886561] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   16.030651] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input12
[   16.030759] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
[   16.030861] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input14
[   16.280125] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[   16.280129] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[   16.280131] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore
[   16.280139] intel_rapl: RAPL package 0 domain package locked by BIOS
[   16.281491] ath: phy0: Enable LNA combining
[   16.282727] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x42
[   16.282728] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x65
[   16.282729] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   16.282731] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   16.282731] ath: Regpair used: 0x65
[   16.294343] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Lenovo EasyCamera (13d3:5171)
[   16.299649] uvcvideo 1-1.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 5 was not initialized!
[   16.299654] uvcvideo 1-1.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 2 was not initialized!
[   16.299657] uvcvideo 1-1.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 3 was not initialized!
[   16.299659] uvcvideo 1-1.4:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[   16.300250] input: Lenovo EasyCamera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/input/input15
[   16.300328] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   16.300329] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   16.318699] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[   16.319070] ieee80211 phy0: Atheros AR9485 Rev:1 mem=0xffffac5841100000, irq=17
[   16.699393] ath9k 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   19.523698] Adding 2006012k swap on /dev/sda7.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:2006012k FS
[   29.366392] audit: type=1400 audit(1499169635.323:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=725 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   29.366400] audit: type=1400 audit(1499169635.323:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session//chromium" pid=725 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   29.378721] audit: type=1400 audit(1499169635.335:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=726 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   29.378727] audit: type=1400 audit(1499169635.335:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=726 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   29.378732] audit: type=1400 audit(1499169635.335:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=726 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   29.378736] audit: type=1400 audit(1499169635.335:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=726 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   29.396272] audit: type=1400 audit(1499169635.355:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=731 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   29.417977] audit: type=1400 audit(1499169635.375:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=732 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   29.417984] audit: type=1400 audit(1499169635.375:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=732 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   29.417989] audit: type=1400 audit(1499169635.375:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd//third_party" pid=732 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   44.439733] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[   44.455171] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[   44.460497] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0: link is not ready
[   45.063025] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: link down
[   45.063078] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0: link is not ready
[   50.040487] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[  234.620022] wlp2s0: authenticate with c0:4a:00:b4:7f:6e
[  234.639897] wlp2s0: send auth to c0:4a:00:b4:7f:6e (try 1/3)
[  234.642229] wlp2s0: authenticated
[  234.645926] wlp2s0: associate with c0:4a:00:b4:7f:6e (try 1/3)
[  234.650220] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from c0:4a:00:b4:7f:6e (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=4)
[  234.650354] wlp2s0: associated
[  234.650366] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[  234.653815] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8348
[  234.653817] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[  234.653818] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[  234.653819] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x3a
[  234.653820] ath: Country alpha2 being used: US
[  234.653820] ath: Regpair used: 0x3a
[  234.653822] ath: regdomain 0x8348 dynamically updated by country IE
```

**Update**

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7,7G        1,2G        5,6G        137M        966M        6,1G
Swap:          1,9G          0B        1,9G
```

---

```
$ swapon -s

Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda7                               partition   2006012 0   -1
```

Comment: Did you get any further with this?

Answer (score 0):

## Partial answer... work in progress...

Edit `/etc/fstab` this way...

```
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

**Change this:**

```
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=1CB9-3478  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
```

**to this:**

```
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=1CB9-3478  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
                                            ^
                                            |_change this
```

**And temporarily change this:**

```
#mount Other drive
UUID=FC08523A0851F3DC /home/bcc/drives/ ntfs rw,auto,users,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=46,uid=1000    0   0
```

**to this:**

```
#mount Other drive
#UUID=FC08523A0851F3DC /home/bcc/drives/ ntfs rw,auto,users,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=46,uid=1000    0   0
^
|_add this
```

and see if the machine boots up faster.

**Update #1:**

Lets first check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #2:**

- boot to the GRUB menu
- highlight the normal boot selection in the menu
- hit the <kbd>e</kbd> key to enter edit mode
- use the arrow keys and find the line that contains "quiet splash"
- delete those two words, leaving ""
- hit the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to exit and continue boot (make sure F10 is the correct key)
- closely monitor the text that appears on the screen, looking for errors, or areas where it's taking a long time to continue

Comment: Tried that, still slow like before.

Comment: @asdfkjasdfjk you made both changes and there was no improvement in boot times? I've added an update to my answer. Please do it and report back. Please show me the `terminal` output of `free -h` and `swapon -s`.

Comment: yes both changes did not improve boot time, also fsck command did not give any errors. I added the output of free and swapon commands in the question under update. Thanks

Comment: @asdfkjasdfjk Please do update #2 and report back.